# Asking what is the point of a final claim in Ayres' construction of the set of integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, integers

Source : Ayres, *Outline of Modern Algebra*

There is a stage in Ayres' construction of the set $I$ of integers that I do not understand. More precisely, I recognize the truth of the claim he makes, but I do not see the ***function or necessity*** of the claim regarding the final goal.

See image below $§4.5$

Ayres has defined

- $I^{+}$, the set of " positive" integers as the set of equivalence classes $[p, q]$ ( with $p, q \in \mathbb N$)  such that $p >q$;
- the integer  $0$ as the equivalence class $[p, p]$ ( for any $p\in \mathbb N$) ;
- $I^{-}$ , the set of "negative" integers as the set of equivalence classes $[p, q]$ ( with $p, q \in \mathbb N$)  such that $p < q$.

He has also established that $I^{+}$ is isomorphic to $N$, via the fact that $I^{+}$ can be defined as the set of all equivalence classes of the form $[r^{*}, 1]$ ( with $ r\in \mathbb N$ and $r^{*}$ the successor of $n$) . He has defined the negative of an equivalence class $[a,b]$ as $[b,a]$ in such a way that $[b,a] = - [b,a]$ and has identified $ - [b,a]$ to the additive inverse of $[b,a]$.

My question is :

> could not Ayres stop here and say that the set I of integers is  $I =
>  I^{+} \cup I^{-} \cup \{0\}$ ?

Instead of this he makes a claim the truth of which I understand, but the ***necessity*** of which is not clear to me.

The claim is that there is a  function from $ 
\mathcal{I}$ the set of all  equivalence classes $[p, q]$ ( with $ p,q \in \mathbb N$) to the set $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$.

Why is this last claim required to construct $I$?

My guess is that Ayres has to show that the set $I^{+} \cup I^{-} \cup \{0\} $ is not only a subset of $I$ but is also equal to $I$ , but I do not see how his claim helps to achieve this goal.

[image]